# linear transformation eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Consider the operator defined by $T(x, y, z) = (-x+2y, 3y, 0)$.
>
> 1. Find the eigenvalues of T and all corresponding eigenvectors.
> 2. Find each generalised eigenvector corresponding to each eigenvalue.

So for 1, I found the matrix with respect to the standard basis $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$. It was upper triangular so I read the eigenvalues from the diagonal entries, which gave me eigenvalues of $-1, 3$ and $0$. I'm just so lost with how to find the corresponding eigenvectors, I feel like this should be really simple.

I know once I have found these eigenvectors for 2, I can simply compute the generalized eigenvectors by solving the equation $(T- \lambda I)^j (v) = 0$ where $v$ is my particular eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you call a generalized Eigenvector ?

Comment: I know that eigenvectors are generalized eigenvectors but the converse is not necessarily true...

Comment: Since the matrix is $\;3\times 3\;$ and it has three *different* eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable and it thus has no generalized eigenvectors that are *not* standard eigenvectors.

Comment: But how do I compute these? like the second column of my matrix w.r.t the standard basis is a linear combination of 2(1, 0, 0) + 3(0, 1, 0) so does that mean these are my eigenvectors?

Comment: @Kierra: you don't answer at all.

Comment: Solving the equation $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ where $A$ is the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis, and $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue, will give you the corresponding eigenvector for $\lambda$. Solve this equation with each eigenvalue in place of $\lambda$.

Comment: ok, so when i solve this I get (0,0,0) as my eigenvector, but I notice any span of (2,1,0) will work and technically (0,0,0) is just (2,1,0) multiplied by 0 anyway so is (2, 1, 0) my eigenvector? My understanding of eigenvectors was that when multiplied by our matrix they give λ lots of the original vector back. Is this incorrect?

Comment: The above comment was made regarding the eigenvalue -1.

Comment: You should never get the zero vector as an eigenvector, since an eigenvector is by definition nonzero. So the matrix $A-\lambda I$ should never be invertible, for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. You may want to re-try your solution to the equation $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Operator**

$$
  \mathbf{T} =
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -1 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Eigenvalues**

To find the eigenvalues, compute $p(\lambda)$, the *characteristic polynomial*.
$$
 p (\lambda ) = \det \left( \mathbf{T} - \lambda \mathbf{I}_{3} \right) = \det
\left[
\begin{array}{ccr}
 -\lambda -1 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 3-\lambda  & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
-\lambda \left( 3 - \lambda \right) \left( -1 - \lambda \right)
$$
The roots $p(\lambda) = 0$ are the eigenvalues: $\lambda = \left\{ 3, -1, 0 \right\}$.

**Eigenvectors**

Solve
$$
  \mathbf{T} v_{k} = \lambda_{k} v_{k} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \left( \mathbf{T} - \lambda_{k} \mathbf{I}_{3} \right) v_{k} = \mathbf{0}
$$

**$\lambda = 3$**

$$
\begin{align}
  \left( \mathbf{T} - 3 \mathbf{I}_{3} \right) v_{1} &= \mathbf{0} \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -4 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 v_{1_{1}} \\
 v_{1_{2}} \\
 v_{1_{3}}
\end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0
\end{array}
\right]
%
 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 
v_{1} =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 2 \\
 0
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

**$\lambda = -1$**

$$
\begin{align}
  \left( \mathbf{T} + \mathbf{I}_{3} \right) v_{2} &= \mathbf{0} \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 v_{2_{1}} \\
 v_{2_{2}} \\
 v_{2_{3}}
\end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0
\end{array}
\right]
%
 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 
v_{2} =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

**$\lambda = 0$**

$$
\begin{align}
  \left( \mathbf{T} + 0 \mathbf{I}_{3} \right) v_{3} &= \mathbf{0} \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -1 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 v_{3_{1}} \\
 v_{3_{2}} \\
 v_{3_{3}}
\end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0
\end{array}
\right]
%
 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 
v_{3} =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 1
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$